# Does Behat started to use selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, behat

I know , behat framework uses Selenium stand alone server to run the files which is not very effective. Has it been updated to use selenium webdriver ??...

Answer (score 0):

> "uses Selenium stand alone server to run the files which is not very effective. Has it been updated to use selenium webdriver"

Using the stand-alone server is irrelevant.  The stand-alone server has both Selenium RC and Selenium WebDriver built in.  It all depends on which classes you are extending from.

So to your question:

> Has it been updated to use selenium webdriver?

Behat is just a DSL of sorts... If you are using Behat with Selenium, then it depends on what **you** are extending your classes from.

Answer (score 0):

Behat itself has nothing to do with selenium.

Web automation is implemented in [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/), which is used with Behat via the [MinkExtension](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension).

All the drivers supported by Mink out of the box are [listen in their docs](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension):

- GoutteDriver
- BrowserKitDriver
- Selenium2Driver
- ZombieDriver
- SahiDriver
- SeleniumDriver

As you probably noticed there are two selenium drivers - [SeleniumDriver](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/selenium.html) supports the old SeleniumRC protocol - while [Selenium2Driver](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/selenium2.html) supports the **webdriver**.